Google analytics batch reports
I have a problem, I am not sure how can I make this work, so i have
ecommerce website and since everyone can sell on it i need to make it
possible for every seller to see how many page views his product has. I
am using Google Analytics for it, I already implemented reporting for
their landing page and code is posted below. So what I need is to
provide GA with urls and it should return me pageviews for every page
for the given time period. Number of urls is between 30-60. I've never
used GA before and I was not able to find solution in documentation so I
would be glad if somebody can help. I tried already some methods but i
got errors that max quota is exceeded.
I am using next.js app router
  import { BetaAnalyticsDataClient } from '@google-analytics/data'
const credential = JSON.parse(
    Buffer.from("", 'base64').toString()
)
export const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient({
    projectId: credential.project_id,
    credentials: {
        client_email: credential.client_email,
        private_key: credential.private_key,
    },
});

async function queryAnalytics(shopUrl: string, startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    const request = {
        property: `properties/{propertyId}`, 
        dateRanges: [{ startDate, endDate }],
        dimensions: [{ name: 'pagePath' }],
        metrics: [{ name: 'activeUsers' }],
        dimensionFilter: {
            filter: {
                fieldName: 'pagePath',
                stringFilter: { value: shopUrl },
            },
        },
    };

    const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport(request);
    const viewers = response.rows?.[0]?.metricValues?.[0]?.value || 0;
    return Number(viewers);
}

I tried fetching more then 10 of them and I get quota exceeded error
